# How to implement a file download in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, file, download

What is the best way to implement, from a web page a download action using asp.net 2.0?

Log files for a action are created in a directory called [Application Root]/Logs.  I have the full path and want to provide a button, that when clicked will download the log file from the IIS server to the users local pc.

Comment: Would you use Response.TransmitFile( for a small file as well?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Does this help:

http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/76293.aspx

```
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=logfile.txt");
Response.TransmitFile( Server.MapPath("~/logfile.txt") );
Response.End();
```

Response.TransmitFile is the accepted way of sending large files, instead of Response.WriteFile.

Comment: A KEY part of this is the Response.End() - without it you will end up with occasionally corrupt downloads, broken digital signatures, all sorts of weirdness.

Comment: Can this be used or modified to grab a remote file from another URL ?

Answer (score 12):

http://forums.asp.net/p/1481083/3457332.aspx

```
string filename = @"Specify the file path in the server over here....";
FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(filename);

if (fileInfo.Exists)
{
   Response.Clear();
   Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileInfo.Name);
   Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", fileInfo.Length.ToString());
   Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
   Response.Flush();
   Response.TransmitFile(fileInfo.FullName);
   Response.End();
}
```

**Update:**

The initial code

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;attachment; filename=" + fileInfo.Name);
```

has "inline;attachment" i.e. two values for Content Disposition.

Don't know when exactly it started, but in Firefox **only** the proper file name was not appearing. The file download box appears with the name of the webpage and its extension (*pagename.aspx*). After download, if you rename it back to the actual name; file opens successfully.

As per [this page](https://www.iana.org/assignments/cont-disp/cont-disp.xhtml), it operates on **First Come First Served basis**. Changing the value to `attachment` only solved the issue.

PS: I am not sure if this is the best practice but the issue is resolved.

Comment: -1: As Martin said, use TransmitFile instead of WriteFile. WriteFile is essentially broken for large files

Comment: I'm doing just this with a button inside of a ModalPopupExtender operating an update panel and it won't work. However, if I move the button outside of the modalpopup/updatepanel area it works flawlessly? Any ideas how to get around this?