# How to implement a file download in ASP.NET AJAX

Tags: asp.net-ajax, download

I would like to use standard ASP.NET file download response, like [in other Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37650/how-to-implement-a-file-download-in-asp-net).

```
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=logfile.txt");
Response.TransmitFile( Server.MapPath("~/logfile.txt") );
Response.End();
```

But inside update panel it does not work. What I have to do, that I will get a file if the download event is triggered inside update panel?

Comment: I'm curious as to why you don't just construct a URL pointing to the file you want to offer to the client, and give that to the browser to use to download your file. ?

Comment: It is a txt file, which normally would be just shown directly in the browser. If the content type is set to "application/octet-stream", I guess the browser will initiate a download to disk instead.

Comment: Well "txt" file is just an example. And it is not directly displayed in the browser. With this response it is always downloadable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, I have found nice blog post on Encosia which describe solution of this ASP.NET AJAX file download problem. It work really nice.

http://encosia.com/2007/02/23/ajax-file-downloads-and-iframes/

Answer (score 2):

You need to have this in a separate aspx that does not use ajax. Ajax is updating existing html markup on a page at the client side. What you try here is replace the responce content on the server side before sending anything to the client.

You could try this:

Have a page called `Download.aspx` that contains the  transmit code you already have.

In your original page, you have a javascript call that calls the download page like this:

```
window.location.replace('Download.aspx');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try making a handler for this work.It is more secure if you can modify well.
For this work,you need to encrypt file path in your page where you put a link for the file.

```
<a href=\"Downloads.ashx?f={0}\" target=\"_blank\">Your link to file</a> 
//{0} -> Encrypted file path
//target = _blank force browser to download file in another window
```

There are lots of encryption techniques in [here](http://www.example-code.com/csharp/encryption.asp)

In your **Handler** page, you need to decrypt the file path into original one so you can read it with `System.IO` libraries.

```
context.Response.ContentType = ""; //-->MimeType for your file's extension
```

You can specify your MimeType by Registry unless your mime-type is static as images.

```
string mimeType = Registry.GetValue(string.Format(@"HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.{0}",
                  Path.GetExtension(decryptedfilePath)), "Content Type", null).ToString();

//Then everything is ready for download

byte[] buffer = File.ReadAllBytes(decryptedfilePath);
context.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0 , buffer.Length);
context.Response.Flush();
```

Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by calling a javascript function, which calls __doPostBack with no __EVENTTARGET.

```
 function GxGridView_Export(exportLink, exportType) {
     var containingGrid = $(exportLink).closest("table .GxGridViewWithSlider");
     __doPostBack('', containingGrid.attr('id') + "###" + exportType);
 }
```

The server side Grid then parses the __EVENTARGUMENT and renders the export file.

```
var eventArg = Page.Request.Form["__EVENTARGUMENT"];
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(eventArg) && eventArg.Contains("###"))
{
    var eventParams = eventArg.Split(new string[] { "###" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    if (eventParams.Length == 2 && eventParams[0] == this.ClientID)
    {
        ExportGrid(eventParams[1]);
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: I initially tried to pass the grid id as the event target, but doPostBack was somehow smart enough to know that's a control inside an ajax panel, and make and ajax postback instead.