# Download file ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to download a file to any location on my computer, but it is sending it right to my downloads folder when I click the button.  The code I am using is below:

I want to be able to chose "Desktop, My Documents, ETC". What am I doing wrong?

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // The file path to download.
    string filepath = @"C:\Test\Test.docx";
    // The filename used to save the file to the client's system..
    string filename = Path.GetFileName( filepath );
    Stream stream = null; 
    try
    {
        // Open the file into a stream. 
        stream = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read ); 
        // Total bytes to read: 
        long bytesToRead = stream.Length; 
        Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"; 
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename ); 
        // Read the bytes from the stream in small portions. 
        while ( bytesToRead > 0 ) 
        {
            // Make sure the client is still connected. 
            if (Response.IsClientConnected) 
            {
                // Read the data into the buffer and write into the 
                // output stream. 
                byte[] buffer = new Byte[10000]; 
                int length = stream.Read(buffer, 0, 10000); 
                Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, length); 
                Response.Flush(); 
                // We have already read some bytes.. need to read 
                // only the remaining. 
                bytesToRead = bytesToRead - length;
            } 
            else
            {
                // Get out of the loop, if user is not connected anymore.. 
                bytesToRead = -1; 
            }
        }
    } 
    catch(Exception ex) 
    {
        Response.Write(ex.Message); 
        // An error occurred.. 
    }
    finally 
    {
        if ( stream != null ) { 
            stream.Close(); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The ContentType should be set as `application/msword` for Microsoft Word documents I thought.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to implement a file download in asp.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37650/how-to-implement-a-file-download-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This have to do with your browser settings - What browser do you use ? What ever, go to the settings of your browser, locate the download options, and tell them to ask you where to save it first.

For google chrome: [Change download locations](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95574&topic=14681&ctx=topic)

For Firefox: [Change what Firefox does when you click on or download a file](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/change-firefox-behavior-when-open-file?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Managing+file+types)

Comment: Wow haha!!!  I just replaced Firefox with Chrome! Ill go slap myself now, thanks!