# opening a file (on the web server) from within a sub procedure

Tags: vb.net

i have the following line of code on a web form

```
lbl_export.text = "<a href=file://w4pvwb019/ccmi4/asp/db/uploads/" & filename & ".csv>Open File</a>"
```

the idea is the user has the option to take some data away for other purposes if required. I would ideally like to replicate the functionality of clicking the link from within a sub procedure, is this possible?

That way I can append some other tasks to the procedure rather than having the user click a link and a button... any help/direction appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to have the (server side) button-click event handler do the download.  This SO answer talks about how to do it. https://stackoverflow.com/a/37656/283895