# How to download .txt files on hyperlink click?

Tags: asp.net, hyperlink, download

I have a hyperlink that I added to my ASP.NET web form. Here is the code:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="lnkDownloadG2" Visible="false" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/Savefile/input_overwriteG2.txt" Target="_blank">Download</asp:HyperLink>
```

When I click on the hyperlink I want the file to download to downloads folder (or whatever folder is specified in browser settings). Instead it is opening in a new tab. How can I force the file to download instead of opening up in a new browser tab?

Comment: Try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37650/how-to-implement-a-file-download-in-asp-net

Comment: Did you try it without Target="_blank"?

Comment: @LouayHamada Where do I put that code? Do I make make a new file? And if yes, what file extension do I use?

Comment: You must use that code into function and call it on click Button. I don't think you can what you want with HyperLink

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer to your question might be in this StackOverflow article:
[how to force a download file prompt instead of displaying it in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23825871/how-to-force-a-download-file-prompt-instead-of-displaying-it-in-browser-with-htm)

For non HTML5 approahc you will have to trick the browser by changing the headers (from your app side or directly at server lever) see this article for more details: http://www.tipsandtricks-hq.com/forum/topic/force-a-file-to-download-instead-of-showing-up-in-the-browser